# Set maximum number of websocket frames per second with Netty

Tags: websocket, netty, vert.x

I know that Netty supports setting the [maximum frame payload](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocketClientHandshaker.html#maxFramePayloadLength%28%29), but I haven't found anything about limiting the number of frames per second. Does Netty natively supports that or do I need to implement that type of protection on my application layer?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ChannelTrafficShapingHandler. You can update it for your needs .